# Mobile App Development Tool for Web Developers/Designers

Tags: iphone, android, ios, ipad

I am a web developer and thus I code in xhtml, css, php, sql databases, etc. I want to create an app for a few sites which interact with my website. However, I have absolutely no knowledge of software programming (ie: C) and don't own a mac.

I have come across phonegap.com which appears to allow people like me to create these apps without any further know-how with software programming.

Before I jump in and start using there solution, I was wondering if anyone else knew any other development tools which might help be develop iphone, ipad and android apps?

It's key that I can access some way to upload files from the device.

Thanks!

Comment: I just noticed that with PhoneGap, to create an ios app you still need a mac :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are many other frameworks

like [appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com)

but phonegap is best one I had found yet
, you can go with it, because,

supports many device. I had use it for android, iPhone and now I'm using for BB too.
 you can write the HTML/CSS code as you like or choose any framework like jQueryMobile, sencha, jQtouch etc, which you cannot in appcelerator.
I suggest you to go with PhoneGap.

other thing, is for creating iPhone app, you need Apple computer (intel base) . it is necessary for any framework